# Django and a nice javascript chart template. Which js library should I use?

Tags: javascript, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am planning a project using Django as a back-end and bootstrap as a basic front end layout. Also I will need a beautiful js charts library.

For the integration between Django and bootstrap there is another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821116/django-and-bootstrap-what-app-is-recommended) where the interesting discussion takes place.

For the integration with a js chart library, I've found a nice library: [nvd3.js](http://nvd3.org/).
Also I've found a django [app](https://github.com/areski/django-nvd3) to integrate nvd3 with django, I've tested it and it works fine, at least with the toy examples.

Does anybody have any experience using it with django?

I am not an expert, I would like some advice from experienced people when combining this tools. I am also opened to any other tool or library.

Comment: also have a look at highcharts: http://www.highcharts.com/

Comment: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/top-jquery-chart-libraries-interactive-charts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When i started with Django i also searched for as many plugins as possible, because i thought that would ease the development process. Why reinvent the wheel i asked myself? But as time went by i found out that many things are better when i did them myself, because almost without exception you will find yourself changing the default behavior or configuration of those plugins. And that's very the hacking begins.

Therefore ask yourself this question:

**Do i really need a plugin that includes a JavaScript file for me and provides some template shortcuts that i rarely use and which i could write myself if need them?**

Ok, i know that the question is biased. But you get my point. Don't overuse django plugins. Instead, do easy stuff yourself and exactly review all plugins for more complex tasks if they fit to your current requirements.

To answer your question directly: Choose a library, include it in your base layout and write the necessary JavaScript code to display the carts.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Alp. Your question is the question. For the moment I am in the point where the django app with the library integrated suffices for my work, but what will happen when the app won't be enough? On the contrary, the good point of using the app is that I can have the plots with much less effort. The inclussion of the plot on the template takes only two lines of code!

Comment: When your requirements change, that two lines of code may clutter up to something ugly, which could be prettier without a plugin. Just a thought, and not necessarily the case in your situation.

Comment: Good thoughts! But without the Django environment, how can I use design patterns to avoid the repetition of code? For example, if I want two identical charts in a page, do I need to copy/paste twice the html/js code? Or would you recommend to use the Django template inheritance system without an specific app?

Comment: Yes, i would advice to create a template which you include where you need it. You can pass variables to templates.